# PHP regex to parse wordpress shortcode attribute

Tags: php, regex, wordpress

I am trying to regex all lightbox wordpress shortcodes and receive their 'link' attribute.

Example:

```
[lightbox link="http://www.test.com/photo1.jpg" width="150" align="none" title="photo 1" frame="true" icon="image"]
[lightbox link="http://www.test.com/photo2.jpg" width="150" align="none" title="photo 2" frame="true" icon="image"]
...
[lightbox link="http://www.test.com/photo5.jpg" width="150" align="none" title="photo 5" frame="true" icon="image"]
```

There can be any number of these shortcodes but I need to get all their link attributes:

```
http://www.test.com/photo1.jpg
```

My pattern I am working with:

```
$pattern = '/\[(\[?)(lightbox)(?![\w-])([^\]\/]*(?:\/(?!\])[^\]\/]*)*?)(?:(\/)\]|\](?:([^\[]*+(?:\[(?!\/\2\])[^\[]*+)*+)\[\/\2\])?)(\]?)/';
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overthinking it a bit

```
preg_match_all('/\[lightbox link="(.*?)".*\]/i', $str, $matches);
```